# Ansible - EC2 Create-Install-AMI-CopyAMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, amazon-ami

I can create an instance, install and create an AMI. I'm stuck when I want to copy that AMI to all available regions.

Something like:
`forEach (region in regions):
    copy-ami to region
done`

What I have:
 - Create Instance
 - Install stuff
 - Create AMI based on values returned from "Create Instance"
 - Copy AMI to all Regions based on "Create AMI" --(Not working!)

Is that the right way to do it?
How would I go about doing that properly?

(I know this is not the right way, seeking to learn how to do it)
Example of the playbook: 
`- hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - { role: copy_ami, ec2_region: [ "ap-south-1" ]}`

error msg:
`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'region'"}`

What the role looks like:
`- ec2_ami_copy:
       source_region: "{{ item.region  }}"
       region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
       source_image_id: "{{ item.image_id }}"
       wait: yes
       tags:
         Name: "{{ item.tags.Name  }}"
       description: "{{ item.tags.Name }}"
      with_items: "{{ec2_storm_ami}}"
      register: ec2_ami_copy`

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show the section of the playbook that is copying the ami as well as the error you get?

Comment: sure.

I know I'm not doing it right. I would like to know the right way.
I tried using a nested loop but hit a dead-end.
Mostly because my lack of understanding I'm sure.

Comment: Can you edit your post (Not the comment) to show the playbook as well as the error.

Comment: Your issue is that you are using "{{ ec2_region }}" instead of "{{ item }}", since you are looping over the module using with_items as per my answer.

Comment: hmm, sorry that was an older code snippet.
I've tried so many ways... but apparently I can't do that?

1st loop - regions
2nd loop - AMIs

can it be done?

Comment: The latest update you posted, show region as not a valid attribute for a dict object. If that key does indeed exist, than you can try this "{{ item['region'] }}"

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole "with_items" & "register" took me sometime to understand fully, espically when using multiple roles.

Solution:
Playbook - containing the AWS plays (Create_EC2, Install/Configure, AMI and AMI_Copy)
Roles - (As noted above)

How did I loop through regions? that proved easier than my initial tries.
The key was to understand how "register" actually works and working with resulting JSON.

The variable "ec2_instance" is registered as part of creating the instance, you can probably just register "ec2_instance.instances" and save yourself some typing. (If you are not using other parts of the json)

Using register means that variable is available across plays in the same playbook. (Was very confused about that part at first)

`- name: Copying AMI
  ec2_ami_copy:
    source_region: "{{ ec2_instance.instances[0].region }}"
    region: "{{ item }}"
    source_image_id: "{{ ec2_instance.instances[0].image_id }}"
    wait: yes
  with_items:
      - us-west-1
      - eu-west-1`

You can probably use an array for the "with_items" here. this is just quick & dirty.

Hope this helps more newbies in the future.

Final recommendation:
Use: `- debug: var=myvariable` with different varitations to make sure you get what you want, running with -vvvv is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for the [ec2_ami_copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_ami_copy_module.html#examples) module.

```
- ec2_ami_copy:
    source_region: us-east-1
    region: eu-west-1
    source_image_id: ami-xxxxxxx
```

Since you want to copy to multiple regions. You can do a [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html#examples) and create a list of regions in the playbook. using the [with_items](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops) plugin will allow you to iterate over a list or a dictionary.

```
- set_fact:
    aws_regions:
      - us-west-1
      - us-west-2

- ec2_ami_copy:
    source_region: us-east-1
    region: "{{ item }}"
    source_image_id: ami-xxxxxxx
  with_items: "{{ aws_regions }}"
```

Comment: Looks great and would it be possible to have the *whole* process automated?

meaning the `source_image_id` will be taken from the previous role which created the AMI?

Comment: If it is on the same host than yes, if not than no. If you are trying to access the ami_id across hosts, than you will have to use a module or write a custom filter. the ec2_ami_find module can help you http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_ami_find_module.html#examples

Comment: So I'm now thinking I should separate that role into a different playbook.
Call ec2_ami_find, get the latest one, copy it to the various regions.
Not sure about copying to all regions though.

Answer (score 0):

Had a tough time because copying is easy but taking the output was tough. I am using a var_input for amiid and then using that in this program.I wanted an output file which has region and ami info. Pasting this working one which will help others who want output to be printed in some file

```
---

- ec2_ami_copy:
    source_region: us-east-1
    region: "{{ item  }}"
    source_image_id: "{{  amiid  }}"
    encrypted: no
    wait: yes
    name: "image copied from {{ amiid  }} of N.Virginia"
    description: "This is working"
  with_items:
    - us-west-1
    - eu-west-1
  register: imageid

- name: Debug variables
  debug:
    msg: "{{ imageid }}"

- name: "Write info to Region-Ami.txt "
  lineinfile:
    dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/Region-AMI-Info/Region-Ami.txt"
    regexp: "^{{ item.key }}"
    line: "{{ item.key }}: {{ '\"' + item.value + '\"' }}"
  with_items:
    - { key: 'aws_region', value: "{{ imageid.results[0].item }}" }
    - { key: 'AMI-ID', value: "{{ imageid.results[0].image_id }}" } 
    - { key: 'aws_region', value: "{{ imageid.results[1].item }}" }
    - { key: 'AMI-ID', value: "{{ imageid.results[1].image_id }}" }
```